# Multiply numbers in double array

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a double array list of doubles, I want to multiply the numbers so that each number being multiplied is not in the same row as the other factors, and the product must be made from 1 number from each row. Since it's a double arrayList there are varying lengths of rows. Any help is appreciated.

Assume this is the arraylist

1.0 , 2.0

1.0 , 2.0

1.0 , 2.0

Math works out like 1*1*1 , 1*1*2 , 1*2*1 , 1*2*2, 2*1*1 , 2*1*2 , 2*2*1 , 2*2*2

I am saving all the products in a new arraylist so the arraylist should hold

1,2,2,4,2,4,4,8

Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you just show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please show us what did you do so far.

Comment: What's the maximum length?

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried it, you will probably realize that it is quite easy?

**Idea:**

- Loop through each ArrayList item by item
- Add *product of these items* to an ArrayList

**Code:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> list2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> list3 = new ArrayList<Double>();

        list1.add(1.0);
        list1.add(2.0);

        list2.add(1.0);
        list2.add(3.0);
        list2.add(5.0);

        list3.add(1.0);
        list3.add(2.0);

        int productListSize = list1.size() *
                list2.size() * list3.size();
        ArrayList<Double> productsList =
                new ArrayList<Double>(productListSize);

        for(double i : list1) {         
            for(double j : list2) {         
                for(double k : list3) {

                    productsList.add(i * j * k);
                }
            }
        }

        for(double d : productsList) {
            System.out.print(d + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1.0 2.0 3.0 6.0 5.0 10.0 2.0 4.0 6.0 12.0 10.0 20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Recursion Method:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DoubleArrayMultiplyRecursion {

    public static void recurMultiply(List<Double> list, double[][] array, int row,
            double result) {
        if (row < 3) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                result *= array[row][j];
                recurMultiply(list, array, row+1, result);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(result);
            list.add(result);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] array = new double[3][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            array[i][0] = 1.0;
            array[i][1] = 2.0;
        }
        List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
        recurMultiply(list, array, 0, 1);
        for(Double d: list) {
            System.out.print(d+",");
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
1.0 // from recursion processing
2.0
2.0
4.0
2.0
4.0
4.0
8.0 // from recursion processing
1.0,2.0,2.0,4.0,2.0,4.0,4.0,8.0, // from result list
```